# Using build.ninja and expecting printing descriptions of the steps when build

Tags: c, linux, ninja

I wanted to learn Ninja and was interested in how to print my custom descriptions
of the build steps. And then I face the strange (to me) behavior of the Ninja.

My platform: Linux Pop OS 22.04 LTS x86_64, Ninja 1.11.1.

I have very basic main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Smart Ninja usage\n");

    return 0;
}
```

No to the build.ninja:

```
# VARIABLES
cc = gcc
cflags = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
ldflags = -lm
target = helloProgram
source = main.c

# RULES
rule compile
  command = $cc $cflags -c $in -o $out

rule link
  command = $cc $ldflags $in -o $out

rule clean
  command = rm -f $target.o

build $target.o: compile $source
build $target: link $target.o
build clean: clean $target
```

Everything is pretty straightforward: just compiling, linking, and then cleaning.
So let's run ninja in the bash:

```
<me>@pop-os:~path/to/build_ninja_file$ ninja
```

And we get this printing to the console:

```
[3/3] rm -f helloProgram.o
```

I already searched for the answer why Ninja print only the last step, it seems to be the default and normal behavior. So let's run ninja again but with -v verbose flag:

```
$ ninja -v

[1/3] gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o helloProgram.o
[2/3] gcc -lm helloProgram.o -o helloProgram
[3/3] rm -f helloProgram.o
```

This is something, but I prefer to have the ability to write something to describe more explicitly what is going on in each step.
So let's add some descriptions for every rule:

```
# RULES
rule compile
  description = Compiling $in to the $out...
  command = $cc $cflags -c $in -o $out

rule link
  description = Linking $in to the $out...  
  command = $cc $ldflags $in -o $out

rule clean
  description = Removing $target.o..
  command = rm -f $target.o
```

Here I face the problem that I can't receive any of my descriptions in the console.
When I run 'ninja' or 'ninja -v' result is the same:

```
$ ninja

[3/3] rm -f helloProgram.o

$ ninja -v

[1/3] gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o helloProgram.o
[2/3] gcc -lm helloProgram.o -o helloProgram
[3/3] rm -f helloProgram.o
```

So I didn't find any way to print descriptions only by using echo. So changed commands:

```
# RULES
rule compile
  description = Compiling $in to the $out...
  command = echo "$description" && $cc $cflags -c $in -o $out

rule link
  description = Linking $in to the $out...  
  command = echo "$description" && $cc $ldflags $in -o $out

rule clean
  description = Removing $target.o...
  command = echo "$description" && rm -f $target.o
```

And run ninja:

```
$ ninja

[1/3] Compiling main.c to the helloProgram.o...
Compiling main.c to the helloProgram.o...
[2/3] Linking helloProgram.o to the helloProgram...  
Linking helloProgram.o to the helloProgram...  
[3/3] Removing helloProgram.o...
Removing helloProgram.o...

$ ninja -v

[1/3] echo "Compiling main.c to the helloProgram.o..." && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o helloProgram.o
Compiling main.c to the helloProgram.o...
[2/3] echo "Linking helloProgram.o to the helloProgram...  " && gcc -lm helloProgram.o -o helloProgram
Linking helloProgram.o to the helloProgram...  
[3/3] echo "Removing helloProgram.o..." && rm -f helloProgram.o
```

Not what I want, but now I can see my descriptions. But it still seems like not-so-smart ninja usage, it's a workaround. And I taught, maybe I can improve it a bit, and get rid from the repetitive lines, so I come to this:

```
# RULES
rule compile
  description = Compiling $in to the $out...
  command = echo "" && $cc $cflags -c $in -o $out

rule link
  description = Linking $in to the $out...  
  command = echo "" && $cc $ldflags $in -o $out

rule clean
  description = Removing $target.o...
  command = echo "" && rm -f $target.o
```

Obviously, when you remove $description you will get only one description if there were two before.

```
$ ninja
[1/3] Compiling main.c to the helloProgram.o...

[2/3] Linking helloProgram.o to the helloProgram...  

[3/3] Removing helloProgram.o...

$ ninja -v
[1/3] echo "" && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o helloProgram.o

[2/3] echo "" && gcc -lm helloProgram.o -o helloProgram

[3/3] echo "" && rm -f helloProgram.o

$
```

At this point, I don't care much about what ninja -v shows me because it seems that I can achieve what I want with simple ninja command.
So I only need to get rid of the empty line that prints after every step.
And I can do this using printf, instead echo:

```
# RULES
rule compile
  description = Compiling $in to the $out...
  command = printf " " && $cc $cflags -c $in -o $out

rule link
  description = Linking $in to the $out...  
  command = printf " " && $cc $ldflags $in -o $out

rule clean
  description = Removing $target.o...
  command = printf "" && rm -f $target.o
```

I find out that I need " " after printf in every step except last one, in the last I need "" after printf and it will prevent me from going to the another additional new line.
But I can keep it.

```
$ ninja
[1/3] Compiling main.c to the helloProgram.o...
[2/3] Linking helloProgram.o to the helloProgram...  
[3/3] Removing helloProgram.o...
$ ninja -v
[1/3] printf " " && gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c main.c -o helloProgram.o
 [2/3] printf " " && gcc -lm helloProgram.o -o helloProgram

 [3/3] printf "" && rm -f helloProgram.o

$
```

That is a winner!) Simple 'ninja' without flag -v work now in a way how I want.

But back to the best practice. **The question is: is it any better way to receive custom-written descriptions in the console?**
Because I don't feel that I use ninja in the right way to show descriptions how it should be, and also I didn't find the answer to my question in the manual:
https://ninja-build.org/manual.html